# Had or did in this context?

Tags: past-tense

I did not expect a reply anymore so when I saw that you did I was very happy .

Is "did " better than" had" I think both are correct but it seems obvious that what I saw came  before I saw it so I did not use past perfect .
What matters here is the fact of answering not the completion of this answer .

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence would be understandable in casual conversation, but the two halves don't match. **A reply** is a noun, so you can't use **had** to imply **had replied.**

> I didn't expect a reply, so when I got yours I was happy

OR

> I didn't expect anyone to reply (verb), so when I saw that you had I was happy.

Comment: And did would not be correct in the second example so when I saw that you did

Comment: I think it would be more natural to use _had_. When you saw the reply, it would already have been sent.

Comment: I don't find ***anymore*** very idiomatic in the cited context (and I always get confused by some pedantic AmE distinction between ***anymore*** and ***any more*** anyway! :). But presumably the intended meaning here is what I might have expressed by *I was **no longer** expecting a reply,...* (because the "discussion thread" or whatever was so long ago).